# Why can't I add a graph to a dynamically inserted svg element?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, appendchild, dagre-d3

I have a simplistic graph as follows:

```js
var g = new dagreD3.graphlib.Graph().setGraph({});
g.setNode(0, { label: "Zero"});
g.setNode(1, { label: "One"});
g.setEdge(0, 1, { label: "Edge"})

var render = new dagreD3.render();
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    svgGroup = svg.append("g");
render(d3.select("svg g"), g);
```

```css
.node rect {
  stroke: black;
  fill: white;
}

.edgePath path {
  stroke: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://dagrejs.github.io/project/dagre-d3/latest/dagre-d3.min.js"></script>

<div id="svgwrapper">
    <svg id="svg-canvas" width=960 height=600></svg>
</div>
```

But must the `svg` element be hard-coded in the HTML code, as above? Can I not insert it dynamically?

Now I don't know how do `d3` and `dagre` function under the hood, however, to my understanding I shouldn't have to! This is because when I call this:

```
var svgg = document.createElement('svg');
document.getElementById('svgwrapper').appendChild(svgg);
svgg.width = "960";
svgg.height = "600";
svgg.id = "svg-canvas";
```

As soon as the above code completes its execution, (to my understanding) an `svg` element is inserted to the document, and an identical one to the one hardcoded in the HTML code... so from now on there should be no difference for any subsequently-executing JS code between the two situations?

Yet this is not the case. Even though I'm inserting the `svg` element before constructing and (trying to) insert the graph, this fails:

```js
var svgg = document.createElement('svg');
document.getElementById('svgwrapper').appendChild(svgg);
svgg.width = "960";
svgg.height = "600";
svgg.id = "svg-canvas";

var g = new dagreD3.graphlib.Graph().setGraph({});
g.setNode(0, { label: "Zero"});
g.setNode(1, { label: "One"});
g.setEdge(0, 1, { label: "Edge"})

var render = new dagreD3.render();
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    svgGroup = svg.append("g");
render(d3.select("svg g"), g);
```

```css
.node rect {
  stroke: black;
  fill: white;
}

.edgePath path {
  stroke: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://dagrejs.github.io/project/dagre-d3/latest/dagre-d3.min.js"></script>

<div id="svgwrapper">
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I insert a graph to a dynamically constructed `svg` element?

Comment: You need to use [`document.createElementNS()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElementNS) for the SVG namespace. See [*"Add SVG element to existing SVG using DOM"*](/q/16488884). Alternatively, using D3 you could do `d3.select("svgwrapper").append("svg")` as this will automatically take care of the namespace.

Comment: @altocumulus Thank you! ... ... When I do this, the graph finally appears! (... ... though the SVG refuses to have height as set. Problem worthy of another question, tho)

Comment: use `d3.select("svgwrapper").append("svg").attr('width', 960).attr('height', 600)`